# What is $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^2+1}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $I_n=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^2+1}dx$

Wolfram Alpha gives an exact value for $n=-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,6,8$ and interestingly enough, it seems $I_n=I_{-n}$.

$$I_0=\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1)$$
$$I_1=I_{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(1)-e^2\operatorname{Ei}(-1)}{2e}$$
$$I_2=I_{-2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sin(1)\left(\operatorname{C}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right)+\operatorname{S}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right)\right)+\cos(1)\left(\operatorname{C}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right)-\operatorname{S}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right)\right)\right)$$
And so on...
$$I_{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\pi}{e^\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
So my question is: For any $n$, what is $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^2+1}dx$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help of Mathematica and using Mellin and Inverse Mellin transform:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(x^n\right)}{x^2+1} \, dx=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\mathcal{M}_x\left[\sin
   \left(x^n\right)\right](s) \mathcal{M}_x\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right](1-s)\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\pi  \sec
   \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{n}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2 n}\right)\right)}{2 | n|
   }\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{n}\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1+s}{2}\right)}{2 | n|  \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2 n}\right) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{s}{2 n}\right)}\right](1)$$

Then using definition of [FoxH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function) function I get:

Mathematica code:

`Pi/(2 Abs[n])*FoxH[{{{1,-(1/n)}}, {{0,1/(2 n)}}}, {{{1/2,-(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{0,1/(2 n)}}}, 1]` for:$n>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{R}$,

Comment: `ReplaceAll[n->2.0][Pi/(2 Abs[n])*FoxH[{{{1,-(1/n)}}, {{0,1/(2 n)}}}, {{{1/2,-(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{0,1/(2 n)}}}, 1]]` gives `1.68357` instead of [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%5Bsin%28x%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D). For `n->0.5`, Wolfram Cloud says “ Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered”. Is there more to the result?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Using MMA **13.3.0** with `ReplaceAll[n -> 2][
   Pi/(2 Abs[n])*
    FoxH[{{{1, -(1/n)}}, {{0, 1/(2 n)}}}, {{{1/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 
        1/2}}, {{0, 1/(2 n)}}}, 1]] // FunctionExpand // N` give me `0.361785`. Very strange.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash .I don't know what going on, see here :https://imgur.com/a/Qa7CfUz

Comment: @ТymaGaidash. I use another alogoritm of **FoxH** function to check correctness for some random values and then my solution is **Correct**.Looks like is a **bug** in Mathematica **13.3.0** and **14.0.0**.